# Keystone JS with field as array of s3 objects

Tags: amazon-s3, keystonejs

How do i define a field with type as array of Types.S3File. Basically what I am trying to achieve is store array of images in S3. I have searched through Keystone Database documentation, they have given how to define type as S3 file. Consider a real life scenario like there is a user and he has multiple images or there is a blog and it contains multiple images, how can I do this using keystone? Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, that is not possible with the S3File type.

While Array fields do exist, they only support Number and String literals at the moment.  The main site documentation for those fields has not been updated, but it looks like it is being worked on.  Here is the WIP documentation for [NumberArray](http://keystonejs.netlify.com/api/field/numberarray/) and [TextArray](http://keystonejs.netlify.com/api/field/textarray/).

You can also create arrays of objects with a workaround.  If you create a new Model with an array as its only field, you can create a nested schema inside of that array.  Unfortunately, if you try to specify any other fields alongside the array you will generate an error.  I have used this technique successfully to create support a Cart for an e-commerce site I am working on.  The Cart schema looks like this:

```
var Cart = new keystone.List('Cart');

Cart.schema.add( {
  items: [{
    itemID: String,
    quantity: Number
  }]
});
```

You can then refer to the Cart model using a [Relationship Field](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#relationship-fields) in another model ( in my case, the User model ).

The downside of this approach is this Cart Model is not editable in the Admin UI.  This is not a problem for me as the cart is updated by middleware, not by a user.  I'm not sure this would work for your use case if you want people to be able to upload their own images, but maybe that's a starting point for a potential solution.

Also I'm not sure if you noticed, but there is a [CloudinaryImages](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-cloudinaryimages) field type that supports multiple images.  That would require you to use Cloudinary, of course, but they do have a free tier.

Hope you find a workaround that suits your needs, while this is a frustrating limitation, I have found Keystone to be a great platform.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have Cloudinary Images but the client was not ready to pay for it and we had an Amazon account, so thought of using S3FileType. Anyways now we have convinced our client to use Cloudinary and we are going with CloudinaryImages.

Comment: this would result : Fields must be specified with a type function  ,  items: [{
    itemID: String,
    quantity: Number
  }]